# Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in and Undefined offset: 1 in php

Tags: php

I have a `php` code as shown below in which I am getting error `Undefined offset: 0 at Line A and Undefined offset: 1 at Line B`

```
<?php 
    $area = &$_SESSION['diagram']->areas[$index];

    // If a new one, create it and link in the session
    if (!is_object($area)) {
        $area = new DiagramArea();
        $_SESSION['diagram']->areas[$index] = &$area;
    }
    for ($i = 0; 5 > $i; ++$i) {
    var_dump($area->files); // Line M                  
    ?>    
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Name / Pattern</legend>
        <input type="text" name="label<?php echo $i; ?>"
            value="<?php echo is_object($area->files[$i]) ? $area->files[$i]->label : ''; ?>" />    // Line A
        <input type="text" name="pattern<?php echo $i; ?>"  
            value="<?php echo is_object($area->files[$i]) ? $area->files[$i]->pattern : ''; ?>" />  // Line B
    </fieldset>
<?php } ?>
```

For debugging purpose, I have added `Line M` in the code above. At `Line M`, I am getting the following o/p:

```
./abc.php:99:
array (size=0)
  empty
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make at `Line A` and `Line B` so that I can avoid the warning in both of those lines.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are performing an `is_object` test, it might be worth it to make sure your object matches what you expect by performing a `property_exists` test, too. However, it might be overkill for this, too (although it doesn't hurt).

This version breaks things on to multiple lines which I personally believe makes it more readable. It also uses the alternative control structure for PHP which doesn't use curl braces. This is optional, but, once I again, I personally find it easier to read when switching between HTML and PHP so that I don't need to chase curly braces around. Lastly, I try very hard to not perform a lot of logic within an HTML attribute, and instead just `echo`. The reason for this is that when debugging, the HTML parsing algorithm might hide PHP errors in the browser.

```php
<?php for ($i = 0; 5 > $i; ++$i) : ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Name / Pattern</legend>
        <input
                type="text"
                name="label<?php echo $i; ?>"
            <?php if (isset($area->files[$i]) && is_object($area->files[$i]) && property_exists($area->files[$i], 'label')): ?>
                value="<?php echo $area->files[$i]->label; ?>"
            <?php endif; ?>
        />
        <input
                type="text"
                name="pattern<?php echo $i; ?>"
            <?php if (isset($area->files[$i]) && is_object($area->files[$i]) && property_exists($area->files[$i], 'pattern')): ?>
                value="<?php echo $area->files[$i]->pattern; ?>"
            <?php endif; ?>
        />
    </fieldset>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Make sure that if you use this that you don't accidentally miss the closing `/>` on the input elements.